# How do I replace wildcards?

Tags: python, numpy, wildcard

I read that using wildcards is frowned upon and should be replaced with a specific command. Below is my program, how should I change the two import * lines at the top?

```
 import pylab
 from pylab import *
 from numpy import *

 list_of_files=[('logfile.txt', 'volts plot')]
 datalist = [( pylab.loadtxt(filename), label ) for filename, label in list_of_files]
 for data, label in datalist:
     pylab.plot( data[:,0], data[:,1], label=label )
 grid(True)
 pylab.legend()
 pylab.show()
```

Comment: `loadtxt` comes from `numpy`; `plot` and `show` are from `matplotlib.pyplot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your program isn't using any of the things that are wildcard-imported in the first place. You can simply remove them.

In addition, your last line does nothing. You probably want `pylab.show()` instead.

Comment: I was able to delete the "from numpy import *" line but not the "from pylab import *" line. Sorry, I left out a line "grid(True)", shown above. The grid(True) line adds a grid to the plot just to make the plotted values easier to read.

Comment: I get "NameError: name 'grid' is not defined"

Comment: Then you want to replace that ``grid`` by ``pylab.grid``.

Comment: Thanks a lot, pylab.grid(True) works fine! I no longer have wildcards in my program.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just remove lines 2 and 3 as they seem to add no further functinality.